# When is it necessary to use the Object.assign() method to copy an instance of an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, constructor

**The following is an example scenario I made up for my own practice of this problem.  If you want to skip straight to the technical details, please see 'Technical Details' below.**

I have a personal project I've been working on to learn JavaScript. Basically, the user can design a shoe by picking available options.

The trick is that the left and right shoe must have the same size, among other properties, but things like color, shoe lace texture, etc. can be independent properties per shoe. (I figured this was a decent way for me to practice object manipulation and inheritance).

The user starts off with designing the right shoe; when the "swap" button is clicked to look at the left shoe, the user currently sees a copy of the right shoe (but inverted).  **Only on the first swapping of shoes is the left shoe generated and made an exact copy of the right shoe. From then onwards, unique options per shoe orientation are preserved.** Then, if the user makes specific changes to *that* left-shoe model, and then switches to the right shoe, the user is supposed to see the exact same right shoe that they had originally designed before they clicked the "swap" button.

So if their right shoe had red laces, they switch to the left shoe view and make the left shoe have a blue lace, then when switching back to the right shoe the user should see red laces!

---

**Technical Details**

When I was writing the code for my main project I was running into trouble with the unique options being perserved. For example, if I made the laces green for the left shoe, the right shoe would always have green laces. Troubleshooting down to the problem was easy because the only time the right shoe was losing it's unique options, such as a red lace, was when I would set the lace color for the left shoe.

```
console.log("THE RIGHT LACE BEFORE: " + rightShoe.laceId);
leftShoe.laceId = 'green';
console.log("THE RIGHT LACE AFTER: " + rightShoe.laceId);
```

What would log to the console was:

> THE RIGHT LACE BEFORE: red
>
> THE RIGHT LACE AFTER: green

Even though I wasn't changing the `rightShoe`, it was being changed whenever I changed the `leftShoe` property.

So I went back to where I first define the `leftShoe` object, which is when the user clicks "swap" for the first time in the life of the script (My amateur thought was *why propagate and fill the `leftShoe` object if the user possibly never customizes the left shoe?* Maybe it's being unnecessarily stingy with data, I don't know). From then onward, *I never redefined the `leftShoe` to be a copy of `rightShoe`* or vice versa. I figured that I was getting hung up by the fact that I was probably doing object referencing and, just like with other languages, I was changing the *reference* and not the value.

Before coming to SO with my troubles, I wanted to make a JSFiddle to recreate the problem. Being that my project is lengthy (around ~1500 lines, including some **THREE.js** for graphics), I did my best to emulate the process. And so [here it is](https://jsfiddle.net/fuayzgxn/2/).

*Except the JSFiddle worked exactly as I expected it to!* The left model preserved it's unique attribute and data set to that attribute. So, I did a little more digging and read about the **Object.assign()** method. So in my original project code (*not* the fiddle), I changed this:

```
leftShoe = rightShoe;
```

to this:

```
leftShoe = Object.assign({}, rightShoe);
```

As excited as I am to have finally gotten this to work, I am equally amused and perplexed because I don't understand why my JSFiddle didn't need the `assign()` method but my identical project code did. Thank you.

Comment: In the first case, both variables reference the same object. In the second case, you're creating a new object (`{}`) and copy all properties using `Object.assign`. Mutating one object won't reflect in the other.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you, I think that's making sense to me now. Quite standard with other languages. But what is throwing me off now is my JSFiddle. If you please take a look at my reference assignment on line 35 of the Fiddle I linked, you'll see that the values for the left option are being changed independently of the fact that it's a referenced object.

Comment: Your fiddle is confusing (with all that currentChoice and leftChoiceExists), and probably you've confused yourself. After the assignment, you can see that `rightChoice.id` == `leftChoice.id` - because both variables refer to the same object.

Comment: @Bergi I don't see where I wrote the comparison expression you wrote, "`rightChoice.id == leftChoice.id`", sorry.

Comment: You didn't, you wrote two `console.log`s that ended up with the same value. Doesn't make a difference. Regardless, I just don't see what is behaving unexpected in that fiddle. Maybe put the output you're getting in your question, and point to the line where you expected something else.

Comment: @Bergi Basically, line 35 I have `leftChoice = rightChoice;`. At this moment in time, I've assigned by reference and `leftChoice.id` = `rightChoice.id` = 999. Then I change `rightChoice.id` to 999. If printed, both `rightChoice.id` and `leftChoice.id` print 999. Then, I set `leftChoice.id` = 444. Printing 'leftChoice.id' gives you 444, not 999, even though it was an object copied by reference.

Comment: Why wouldn't `leftChoice.id` be 444 right after you have set it to that value? Of course, `rightChoice.id` will now give 444 as well, since they still point to the same object.

Comment: @Bergi Why I'm confused is because the exact same use in my main project code was resulting in 'leftChoice.id' (or in my project's case, 'leftShoe.laceId') _not_ changing it's value. The fiddle is having it's value changed when I manually set it in line 17. This didn't work in my main project without the `assign()` method.

Comment: It *will* change it's value when you assign to it. Most probably you have overwritten it (possibly via `rightChoice` that points to the same object) before logging it.

Comment: @Bergi Wow. It totally makes sense now! Thank you so freaking much! What was happening is that I was thinking that any changes to `rightChoice` may change values in `leftChoice`, since I explicitly set `leftChoice` to be a reference object of `rightChoice`. What I _wasn't_ realizing was that any changes to `leftChoice` was _also_ changing `rightChoice`!!! Aka, my thinking was `rightChoice` ---> `leftChoice`, not `rightChoice` <---> `leftChoice`, if that makes sense. Again, thank you so much. Please answer this so I can give you points :[

Comment: It's more like `rightChoice --> {} <-- leftChoice` - you're not referencing a variable, the variable (holds a value that) references the object.

Comment: @Bergi Man, you keep giving and giving lol, I can't thank you enough. So, what's the point of using `this` in my constructor if it's not preserving the data for that instance of `this`?

Comment: Huh? What's the problem with `this` now? The constructor has nothing to do how references to the instances are passed around.

Comment: @Bergi It all makes sense to me now, thank you :]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Object.Assign makes a new COPY of the left shoe, including all enumerable OWN properties.  When you use leftshoe = rightshoe, you are making a REFERENCE to the left shoe.  A reference points to the same object, not a NEW COPY.  Thus changing a property of the reference is actually changing the original, as you noted.

Comment: Thank you! So I have to ask, why isn't this the case with my JSFiddle I linked to? I use the reference assignment and yet am still able to make changes. Check out line 35 of my Fiddle and then go through the buttons I made while watching the output.

Comment: The fiddle seems broken to me.  rightId gets set to 444 when it should stay 999

Comment: thanks a lot now it makes more sense to use it in react with redux